# A string encrypted (AES) after decryption prints the same value , but false on equals()

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

My program sends a string encrypted (AES) with received session key to Client to prove the key is correct. 
Client should decrypt it, get the string and verify it with original one.

Program works fine. It encrypts and decrypts the string. It prints the string I need, but gives me false when I do String.equals(string).
I can figure out why.
There is the encryption part of my code:

```
// ----create a challenge for Client (to check if the session key is correct)--------

public void sessionKeyVer(String challenge, File out) throws Exception{

    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec); // switching mode for encryption

    CipherOutputStream os = new CipherOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(out), aesCipher); //output stream to another file 

    os.write(challenge.getBytes("UTF-8"));// function to copy String to outputstream
    os.close();     //close the stream

}
```

There is the decryption part:

```
public boolean sessionKeyVer(File file) throws Exception{
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, aeskeySpec); // switching mode for decryption

    CipherInputStream is = new CipherInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), aesCipher); //output stream to another file 
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    int i;
    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
    while((i=is.read(b))!=-1) {
          os.write(b, 0, i);
      }

    is.close();
    os.close();
    String file_string = new String(b,"UTF-8");
    System.out.print(file_string);
    return file_string.equals(challenge); //return false

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Check the lengths of the two strings.

Comment: I have checked the file_string length. It was 1024 (size of the array I created), so I have changed the byte array size   byte[] b = new byte[challenge.length()]; and it works fine. Thank you all

Comment: Rather than that, you should keep track of how many bytes you've read... which EJP's answer effectively does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part is the *encryption* part. The *second* part is the decryption part.

The second part is wrong. You are decrypting the last part of the still-encrypted buffer, rather than the entire, decrypted `ByteArrayOutputStream,` and committing a size error in the process too.

```
String file_string = new String(b,"UTF-8");
```

should be

```
String file_string = new String(os.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think your solution wont work, because I read bytes from the file after a CipherInputStream filter, so the byte array should contents only my string in bytes (already decrypted). After that I just convert bytes to string.

Comment: I suggest you try it instead of just arguing about it. You're reading ciphertext into the byte array, and decrypting it somewhere else that you're making no further use of. What therefore is the basis of your expectation that you can magically print the byte array as plaintext?

Comment: Thank you, I have tried and it creates a zero string.

Comment: That can only happen if you hadn't written anything to the `ByteArrayOutputStream,` for example if the input from the socket was empty, or you constructed the `String` in the wrong place in the code.